# How to select data from array when having only 1 piece of array-data (own data class)

Tags: java, android, arrays

Hi and all the best from Germany,

having a problem with an array.

I have an array with 2 sets of data (data 1 (a, b, c), data 2 (d, e, f)).

Now I want to extract "d" and "e", when having the Information "f".

My code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

[...]
class Data {
    public Data(int category,
                String quality,
                String title,
                String snippet,
                float lng,
                float lat,
                String homepage,
                String phonenumber,
                float distance,
                float duration

               )
    {
        super();
        this.category = category;
        this.quality = quality;
        this.title = title;
        this.snippet = snippet;
        this.lng = (float)lng;
        this.lat = (float)lat;
        this.homepage = homepage;
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
        this.distance = (float) distance;
        this.duration = (float) duration;

    }
    int category;
    String quality;
    String title;
    String snippet;
    float lng;
    float lat;
    String homepage;
    String phonenumber;
    float distance;
    float duration;

}

Data[] data = {
        new Data(1,
                "***",
                "title1",
                "snippet1",
                0.0f,
                0.0f,
                "http://www.something.something",
                "tel:+00000000",
                0,0),

        new Data(1,
                "***",
                "title2",
                "snippet2",
                0.0f,
                0.0f,
                "http://www.something.something",
                "tel:+00000000",
                0,0),
/**
        new Data(1, -79.402206f,43.657688f, "College St",
                "Lots of discount computer stores if you forgot a cable or need to buy hardware."),

        new Data(1, -79.390381f,43.659878f, "Queens Park Subway",
                "Quickest way to the north-south (Yonge-University-Spadina) subway/metro line"),

        new Data(1, -79.403732f,43.666801f, "Spadina Subway",
                "Quickest way to the east-west (Bloor-Danforth) subway/metro line"),

        new Data(1, -79.399696f,43.667873f, "St George Subway back door",
                "Token-only admittance, else use Spadina or Bedford entrances!"),

        new Data(1, -79.384163f,43.655083f, "Eaton Centre (megamall)",
                "One of the largest indoor shopping centres in eastern Canada. Runs from Dundas to Queen."),
 */
};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
[...]

    // 8. when the infowindow ist clicked
    myMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    String titleOfClickedMarker = marker.getTitle();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),titleOfClickedMarker, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// HERE I NEED HELP: I now have the title (for example title 1), and now the Point: HOW DO I GET THE OTHER INFORMATION OF THE "TITLE1" data set (e.g. snippet 1, etc.). 

                }
            }
    );


}
```

I appreciate every help, even if short.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing all your `Data` instances in an array, you can consider storing them in a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), assuming you are working with Java. So essentially, your `data` instance now becomes:

```
class Data{
  /* etc... */
  public String getText(){
    return this.title;
  }
}

Data data1 = new Data(1, "***", "title1", "snippet1",
                      0.0f, 0.0f, "http://www.something.something",
                      "tel:+00000000", 0,0);

Data data2 = new Data(1, "***", "title2", "snippet2",
                      0.0f, 0.0f, "http://www.something.something",
                      "tel:+00000000",
                      0,0);
/* etc... */

HashMap<String, Data> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Data>();
for(int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) // add data instances in a loop. Define your own dataCount
  hashMap.add(data.getTitle(), data);

/* etc... */

myMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    String titleOfClickedMarker = marker.getTitle();
    Data data = hashMap.get(titleOfClickedMarker);
    /* etc.. */
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are three addional questions: (1) How can "data1", "data2", etc. be stored in a HashMap automatically (e.g. via for-Loop). (2) What does "data1.getTitle()" mean? Is this meant to have the "title1" twice, at first place and on third? (3) The "data = hashmap.get(titleOfClickedMarker)": What exactly does this produce: the set of the data, e.g. data1 (with "1", "***", "title1", etc. in it)? Appriciate your comment.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include your new questions (1) and (2). I am not sure what your question (3) meant.